# Class within a class in a header file being called in main

Tags: c++, function, class, header, scope

So a format of the code looks like this:

```
class patient{
public:
    char FirstName[30];
    char LastName[30];
    char SID[20];

};

class Register{
    private:
    int PatientNum;
    patient List[];

    public:
    void OutputList ();

};
```

Then later I've got the function using the Register like so:

```
void Register::OuputList() {...}
```

Now, this is all in a header file. However, when I try to implement the function OutputList() in the main it won't let me. How do I go about this, so in the main the function will compile?

Also, I have another function that was defined outside of the scopes with the patient class such as:

```
patient Add(){...}
```

when using this function in the form of Add(); in main, it works.

Comment: Obviously you should put the method's definition outside of the `main` or inside the class declaration.

Comment: *it won't let me* — Does your compiler actually tells you "Sorry Dave I can't let you do that"? You may want to install one that outputs actual error messages you can analyze.

Comment: Also, why can't you use strings or STL containers? You could easily convert all the char arrays into std::strings, and you could easily avoid a lot of problems later on by declaring your list as `vector<patient> List` or `list<patient> List`